# jQuery ajax() function - content doesn't load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, netbeans

I'm using jQuery and I've got problem with ajax() function. It doesn't seem to be a difficult problem but anyway I don't know what's going on. I'd like to load content from another html file using ajax, here's my code:

```
$(function(){
$('.submit-1').click(function(){
    $('.right').load('ajax.html .page-2');
});});
```

It works perfectly when I run it on NetBeans IDE - when I click the button, content loads. The problem is that it doesn't work without Netbeans, for example - when I open index.html.

Comment: If the page is being redirected, use `event.preventDefault();` or `return false;` from the event handler.

Comment: Do you see any errors in browser's developers console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run your code in a server(apache,nginx), ajax cannot run without a server

use prevent default if your element is a link or a submit button

```
$(function(){
$('.submit-1').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.right').load('ajax.html .page-2');
});});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use preventDefault function. hope it will help

```
$(function(){
 $('.submit-1').click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 $('.right').load('ajax.html .page-2');
});});
```

Comment: oops! a big mistake :|

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it solves your problem when you installing a server. With [Apache](https://www.apachefriends.org/de/index.html) it's very easy to do this. Just install it and configure/start Apache. With XAMPP you can also install a Database and it supports PHP and PERL.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
$('.submit-1').click(function(){
    $.get( "ajax/test.html", function( data ) {
        $( ".result" ).html( data );
        alert( "Load was performed." );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution

```
$(function(){
$('.submit-1').click(function(){     
$.get('yourURL/home.html', function (data) {
    $('.right').append(data);
   });
});
```

you need to append the data retuned from server. The 'data' variable in the call back function holds the complete html from home.html